# How to SELECT from events_* AND events_intraday_* tables using SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery and SQL. I'm trying to return data from Google's BigQuery. I have a query that can get data from tables of form EITHER events_* OR events_intraday_*, but I'm at an early stage and would really like to pull all the data from both sets of tables with a single query. [It seems like this should be trivial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/) but nothing I've tried has worked. I can't find an example in any doc which explains how to combine UNNEST with multiple tables in Google SQL.

Here's my original working query:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM
  `analytics_xxx.events_intraday_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  AND event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

Variation 1:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM
  `analytics_xxx.events_intraday_*`, `analytics_xxx.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  AND event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

Variation 1 error: Column name event_params is ambiguous at [17:15]

Variation 2:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM
  `analytics_356435236.events_intraday_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param,
  `analytics_356435236.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  AND event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

Variation 2 error: Column name event_params is ambiguous at [19:15]

Variation 3:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM
  (`analytics_xxx.events_intraday_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param),
  (`analytics_xxx.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param)
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  AND event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

Variation 3 error: Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got "," at [16:48]
SQL

Variation 4:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM
  (`analytics_xxx.events_intraday_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param)
JOIN
  (`analytics_xxx.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param)
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  AND event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

Variation 4 error: Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got "," at [16:48]

...and so on. I've tried a dozen other variations, but nothing has worked. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `events_*` and `events_intraday_*` are in the same dataset ?

Comment: Yup, same dataset

Comment: Then `events_intraday_*`  sharded tables belong to `events_*` tables as well, so aren't `events_*` enough ?

Comment: That doesn't work, I think because the table suffix is analysed as a date so in events_intraday tables, the part after events_ is not a valid date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to see what would happen, I asked ChatGPT, which gave me the following code that seems to work perfectly:

```
SELECT
  user_id as user_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
  experiment_id_param.value.string_value AS experiment_id,
  variation_id_param.value.int_value AS variation_id,
  geo.country as country,
  traffic_source.source as source,
  traffic_source.medium as medium,
  device.category as device,
  device.web_info.browser as browser,
  device.operating_system as os
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `analytics_xxx.events_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT * FROM `analytics_xxx.events_intraday_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}' AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}'
), UNNEST(event_params) AS experiment_id_param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS variation_id_param
WHERE
  event_name = 'experiment_viewed'  
  AND experiment_id_param.key = 'experiment_id'
  AND variation_id_param.key = 'variation_id'
  AND user_id is not null
```

I had previously tried "UNION ALL" but the key change seems to be splitting the "WHERE" into a section for selecting the table by date suffix, and a selection for selecting the record parameters.

Comment: OMG, this strange _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{{startYear}}{{startMonth}}{{startDay}}'  AND '{{endYear}}{{endMonth}}{{endDay}}' actually works )) Also I do not recommend to use events_intraday_ table in analytics because it is too unreliable in anywhere long range statistics

Comment: Sorry - I think that text is actually a placeholder and in the real code, I put in actual dates '20230101' etc

Comment: I've tested it, it actually works ))) I can't find documentation on it but it is working fine. My bet it is built in global variables